# VS Code auto generate interface methods in php class?

Tags: php, methods, interface, visual-studio-code, implements

How can i "auto implement"/generate methods from interfaces into PHP classes?
I wanna use **VS Code** for it

interface :

> ```
> interface MyInterface{  public function myMethod($param); }
> ```

class :

```
Class MyClass implements MyInterface{
//myMethod should be auto generate by vscode
   public function myMethod($param){

}
}
```

does this feature exist in **VS Code**?

Comment: Any news about that ? Do you find a solution ?

Answer (score 4):

VSCode doesn't support this out of the box for PHP. For what I know, this is not available through any of the existing PHP plugins like PHP Intelephense or PHP IntelliSense.
PHP Intelephense does autocomplete methods from implemented interfaces though.

**edit 25-08-2021**

[Intelephense](https://intelephense.com/) premium has such feature, you need to buy a very inexpensive license at https://intelephense.com/

Comment: [PHP extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DEVSENSE.phptools-vscode) provides the code refactoring features, including implementing interfaces, missing abstract methods, and more. There is a 30-day free trial and an annual subscription fee.

Answer (score 4):

Check **PHP tools** extension: `DEVSENSE.phptools-vscode`.

It is providing what you need for free for 30 days as far as I understood.

Comment: Confirming. [PHP extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DEVSENSE.phptools-vscode) provides code actions, code refactorings, code fixes, code lenses, inlay hints, and much more. Try the 30-day free trial. Then there is an annual subscription fee.

Answer (score 1):

when you focused the line with cursor,

you could click icon! [image: icon]

[image: click icon]

Comment: Which plugin is providing this behavior for you?

Comment: @wearego PHP Intelephense https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client does have this feature. You just need to buy license in order to access features. Like $12