# How can I automatically add methods of my interface to my class in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, interface, autocomplete

I want to add methods of this interface to my class automatically but I couldn't find a way.

I use Visual Studio Code editor. I don't want to use PhpStorm or any other IDE/editor, so I really need to solve this problem.

My code :

```
<?php 

use App\Payment\PaymentInterface;

class MyTest implements PaymentInterface
{
    
}
```

When I type implement PaymentInterface, I want the IDE to automatically add the method of my interface to my class.

Is this possible?

Comment: not sure this is possible (with php) out of the box in vscode. you might be able to find an extension but I didn't have any luck

Comment: Any news about that ? Do you find a solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately ...

Comment: I believe it's answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56472568/19985104. Have a nice day ^owo^